# Android Service to perform action on location change

Tags: android, service, location

I am trying to create a service that check the location of the user every few mins and perform certain code on location change.

Here's the onCreate code of my service.

```
public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i(TAG, "Service creating");

        //timer = new Timer("TweetCollectorTimer");
        //timer.schedule(updateTask, 1000L, 60 * 1000L);
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
          lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, locationListener);
      }
```

It is able to do something when my location change. However i am getting the following warning in my logcat "sending message to a handler on a dead thread"

I would like to know what's the problem and is there any better way to implement what i wanted to do?

Comment: Note that this service is a background service

Comment: what code do you execute on location change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be wary of your location listener and your activity lifecycles.

If you request location updates in the `onCreate()` method of your activity, be sure to unregister it later on, like for instance `onDestroy()`, although in my opinion it would be better to register it `onStart()` and unregister it `onStop()`.

It seems like your location listener is calling a method on an activity that may already be dead.

If you plan on implementing location detection in more than one activity, it might be wise to create a base class containing a listener calling an abstract method when the location updates. You can push it further by overriding `onStart()` to register your listener and `onStop()` to unregister your listener. Although, don't forget to call the super constructor both in that abstract class and the children classes.

Hope it helps and it wasn't too confusing!

**EDIT:**

Code example goes below:

```
public abstract class LocationActivity extends Activity {

    private LocationListener mLocationListener;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
                updateLocation(location);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(final String provider,
                    final int status, final Bundle extras) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(final String provider) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(final String provider) {
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // register your listener with the location manager
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // unregister your listener from the location manager
    }

    protected abstract void updateLocation(Location location);
}
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply as i went on to develop on other areas first. You mentioned creating a base class. I am not too sure on this, able to provide a brief example and i will try to work from there? Thanks.

Comment: I've added a short code example. Basically the workflow is, extending this class, creating a listener onCreate, registering the listener onStart, unregistering the listener onStop (you'll have to check by yourself the code to register and unregister, since I can't figure it out by head).
When there's an update, updateLocation is fired and the Activity extending this LocationActivity will have to implement this method to handle the new location. Hope it can point you in the right direction!

Comment: Ok so basically now i don't have to add anything in this base class. Let's say if i have 2 activity that need to implement it, I have to create 2 children extending this class with the respectively implementation. Then in the 2 activities i then use them: locationListenerChild1 mLocationListener = new LocationListener(); And after that i don't have to do anything else and the listener will take care of what to do onLocationChanged in that activity. Correct me if i am wrong.